# How to make my txt file put each numbers I want into rows

Tags: python, file, numbers, rows

So I want to make my txt file only put my numbers but in rows inside of my txt file. So far I have what my code put in my txt but all I want it to do is sort it on each other

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

json_data = '''
    {"previousPageCursor":null,"nextPageCursor":"23971776_1_0c424f10e6a8a73392287b04ef20267c","data":[{"buildersClubMembershipType":"None","userId":29661084,"username":"HeartlessGod","displayName":"HeartlessGod"},{"buildersClubMembershipType":"None","userId":2736666,"username":"thunderbolt777","displayName":"thunderbolt777"},{"buildersClubMembershipType":"None","userId":9509309,"username":"FlyScript","displayName":"FlyScript"},{"buildersClubMembershipType":"None","userId":9933671,"username":"XcRaZeD","displayName":"XcRaZeD"},{"buildersClubMembershipType":"None","userId":1484736,"username":"dodo212","displayName":"dodo212"},{"buildersClubMembershipType":"None","userId":10026270,"username":"wassup99","displayName":"wassup99"},{"buildersClubMembershipType":"None","userId":559756,"username":"jack593","displayName":"jack593"},{"buildersClubMembershipType":"None","userId":6160107,"username":"spectacularmario","displayName":"spectacularmario"},{"buildersClubMembershipType":"None","userId":7706434,"username":"dustyscoobydoo","displayName":"dustyscoobydoo"},{"buildersClubMembershipType":"None","userId":1335986,"username":"dooter","displayName":"dooter"}]}
'''


test = (requests.get("https://groups.roblox.com/v1/groups/" + str(650266) + "/roles/" + str(7505671) + "/users"))
outfile = open(r"D:\untitled\Lib/tester.txt", "w")
#outfile.write(str(test.text.encode('UTF-8')))
parsed_data = parsed_data = requests.get("https://groups.roblox.com/v1/groups/" + str(650266) + "/roles/" + str(7505671) + "/users").json()

for d in parsed_data['data']:
    outfile.write(str(d['userId']))
```

[image]

Comment: Depending on how long you want the rows to be, you could also write a newline character to the file every nth iteration, where n is the length of the row

Comment: @Teisql, was my answer useful?

Comment: Yes it was very useful thank you

Answer (score 3):

You need to append the new line when using `write`, so try the following:

```py
outfile.write(f"{d['userId']}\n")
```

If you are using a previous version than Python 3.6, use the following:

```py
outfile.write(str(d['userId']) + "\n")
```